# Two problems related to NP-Hard and why they are true?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, turing-machines, np-complete

$F(z_1,...,z_n)$ is a Boolean expression. The assignment of variable ($x_1,...,x_n \in {0, 1}$) is the answer of $F$, if $F$ for that assignment equals to $1$.

If that case is true and the conditions are met, then both of them are considered to be *NP-Hard*.

---

A) The *number* of *answers* of $F$ in $DNF$ format.

B) The *number* of *answers* of $F$ in $CNF$ format.

> DNF and CNF are [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

---

Can anyone describe to me in clear, simple, and concise words why both of them are true?

Comment: While you might get an answer here, I think this question is better suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Jared Thanks. I try another site if no answer here... thanks. I think there are more expert person here that CS.

Comment: I am out of the loop and don’t feel confident to write an answer, but I think you should restrict to $n\geq3$. Then $n\mathsf{SAT}$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete (in particular $\mathsf{NP}$-hard and it seems to me that you are supposed to show that solving one of your problems A) or B) would provide a solution to $n\mathsf{SAT}$, making it at least as hard it, hence $\mathsf{NPH}$.